# How should I capitalize "on which" using headline-style capitalization?

Tags: american-english, pronouns, capitalization, headline-case

How should I capitalize *on which* in the headline *The Construction of Those Terms on which the Parties Agree*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would capitalize "**Which**," just as you have capitalized "**Those**."

That said, the title is awkward. What does "The Construction" mean? Do you mean to say, "**Definition of Terms Used in this Contract**"? Or simply, "**Terms of Contract**"?

Comment: I agree that it's awkward. (I didn't write it; I just came across it in a document.) "Construction" is a term of art in patent law—see  http://patentlyo.com/patent/2009/09/claim-construction-a-structured-framework-1.html ("The construction of patent claims plays a critical role in nearly every patent case.").